# Performance of web service

Tags: android, web-services

In my app I have to call web services minimum 25 to 30 times in one particular page.

My app becomes slow for this.

I use XML Web service.

My code is :-

```
 for(int i=0 ; i < careplan_disease_Parser.DiseaseID.size() ;i++){

           String disId=careplan_disease_Parser.DiseaseID.get(i);

           String method = "GetCarePlan_Comment?CurrentValue=" + 0
                    + "&OptionId=" + disId + "&DiseaseID=" + disId + "&OrgId=" + orgId + "";
            String link = "GetCarePlan_Comment_Disease";

            new MyAsyncTask123().execute(link, method);
            sleep();
            method = null;
            link = null;    

       }
```

I Want to improve performance to call web service.
If i don's put sleep() method then all data will not get.

Please help me how can i do this??

Thanks in advance.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your will get your data in onPostExecute()

remove sleep

because of sleep thread is not running in parallel (UI Thread and AsyncTask Thread)

sleep holds the for loop and will makes app look like hanged

Comment: If i don't put sleep(), then all data will not received, For this reason i have to put sleep();

Answer (score 0):

1. Get small portions of DiseaseID collection, then you can run two or more AsyncTasks in parallel. You don't need to call `sleep()` in each AsyncTasks.
   Ex: 1st AsyncTask runs for DiseaseID 0-10
   2nd AsyncTask runs for DiseaseID 11-20
   3rd AsyncTask runs for DiseaseID 20-end
2. You can build your web service much light weight, if you use a mechanism like JSON over XML.

Answer (score 0):

I found One Solution. In MyAsyncTask123() class Put `iscancelled();` after getting data.

This will decrease some time , I reduce nearly 25 seconds.

If there is any other solution then Please share it.

Thank you.